# Derivation of $~\coth \left(\sinh^{-1} (x) \right)= {\sqrt{1+x^2} \over x }$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I want to derive the following equation.

$$ \color{fuchsia}{\begin{align}
\coth \left(\sinh^{-1} (\theta) \right)&= {\sqrt{1+\theta^2}  \over \theta }~~~\text{for}~~\theta\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}
\end{align}}  $$

BTW since $~ \theta>0 ~$ is held, $~ \sinh^{-1}(\theta)>0 ~$ is also held.

I've prepared the following 2 eqns which can be used to derive the pink equation.

$$\begin{align}
\coth(t)&= {{e^{t}+e^{-t}} \over e^{t}-e^{-t} }~~~ \text{for}~~t\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}  \\
\sinh^{-1}(\theta)&=\ln \left(\theta+\sqrt{1+\theta^2}  \right)
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
y&:=\coth(t)\\
y&={e^{2t}+1 \over e^{2t}-1 }\\
\left(e^{2t}-1 \right)y&= e^{2t}+1\\
ye^{2t}-y&=e^{2t}+1\\
e^{2t}\left(y-1 \right)&=1+y\\
e^{2t}&= {y+1 \over y-1 }\\
y=1~~&\text{is not held under the condition of }~t>0\\
\ln \left(e^{2t} \right) &= \ln \left({y+1 \over y-1 } \right)\\
2t&=\ln \left({\coth(t)+1 \over \coth(t)-1 } \right)\\
2 \sinh^{-1}(\theta)&=\ln \left( { \coth(\sinh^{-1}(\theta))+1\over \coth(\sinh^{-1}(\theta))-1 } \right)
\end{align}$$

I think my this approach can' be proceeded from here.

I have the hint that using $~ \exp \left(-\sinh^{-1}(t) \right)= {1 \over \theta+ \sqrt{1+\theta^{2}}  } ~$ can(may) lead to derivation of the pink equation but I've had no idea how to utilize it and even can't derive that equation.

Which operation should I consider first?

Comment: Have you tried just setting $t = \ln\left(\theta + \sqrt{1+\theta^2}\right)$ in $\dfrac{e^t+e^{-t}}{e^t-e^{-t}}$?

Comment: I haven't done it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much easier to think in terms of hyperbolic function identities rather than converting to exponentials and logs.

$$\begin{cases}\coth t = \frac{\cosh t}{\sinh t} \\ \cosh t = \sqrt{1+\sinh^2 t}\end{cases} \implies \coth(\sinh^{-1}(\theta)) = \frac{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(\sinh^{-1}\theta)}}{\sinh(\sinh^{-1}\theta)} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}}{\theta}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have,
$$e^t=\sqrt{1+\theta^2}+\theta\quad (1)$$
Take reciprocals,
$$e^{-t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}+\theta}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}+\theta}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}-\theta}{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}-\theta}$$
$$=\sqrt{1+\theta^2}-\theta\quad(2)$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, you get
$$e^t+e^{-t}=2\sqrt{1+\theta^2}$$
$$e^t-e^{-t}=2\theta$$
yielding the desired result. Hope this helps. :)